# getting Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] while running my first android app

Tags: android

I am new to android and trying to run my first android app using Android Studio. My app is not getting installed in the emulator device and I am getting this message.

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

After searching on net I found that this happens when the device has API level lower than that of the minSdkVersion. But that is not the case here. Following is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
buildToolsVersion "20"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.parikshit.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
}
```

The emulator device is Nexus 5 with KitKat version.I don't know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
compileSdkVersion 20
```

And

```
targetSdkVersion 20
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil `This does not provide an answer to the question.` What makes you say that? Please read the answer again. It suggests steps to do and does not "critique or request clarification" from the OP.

Comment: instead of writing two line you can write it in comment.

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question.